# How to patch an object method in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

In a class, I have an attribute (`self.data`) which is a pandas.DataFrame.

I have a method `save()` in the class that basically calls `self.data.to_csv()` with some validations beforehand. In the test, I would like to patch this so that it won't actually store data in the directory, I just need to make sure it runs as mock.

I couldn't wrap my head around how to patch it. So far I have:

```
# Myclass.py

import pandas as pd
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

    def save(self, path):
        # Do something validation
        # I would like to patch the line below. 
        self.data.to_csv(path)
```

In `test_myclass.py`:

```
from unittest import mock
import Myclass

@mock.patch(Myclass.to_csv)
def test_save(myclass_fixture):
    myclass_fixture.save(path)
```

I got the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Portfolio' has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Answer (score 3):

`to_csv` is a method of `DataFrame`, so you have to patch that method, as it is imported in the production code:

```python
@patch("myproject.Myclass.pd.DataFrame.to_csv")
def test_save(patched_to_csv):
    data = some_test_data  # this may come from a fixture
    my = MyClass(data)
    my.save("some_path")
    patched_to_csv.assert_called_once()
```

This assumes that your project layout is `myproject/Myclass.py`.

Note that the first parameter to `patch` is not an object, but a string, containing the path to the patched object (see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6) for what it shall contain).

It also looks like you want to take your class from a fixture - in this case you have to add this fixture to the arguments:

```python
@pytest.fixture
def myclass_fixture():
   test_data = ...
   yield MyClass(test_data)

@patch("myproject.Myclass.pd.DataFrame.to_csv")
def test_save(patched_to_csv, myclass_fixture):
    myclass_fixture.save("some_path")
    patched_to_csv.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: hmm. It actually complained Myclass has no attribute pd.

Comment: Note that `Myclass` here is the module name, not the class name, and by `module_path_to_my_class` I mean the path to the module `Myclass`, not the class, e.g. `myproject.Myclass.pd....`. I'll probably change that to make it clearer.